# Hide datalist rows if empty in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to hide a datalist rows if they are empty, any ideas how to do that using a CSS class or any other best solution. I tried to use render attribute but it doesn't work fine for me. here is some code snippet for my code

```
<p:tab id="airAccor" title="AIR" titleStyle="height: 20px; font-size :8pt; font-weight: bolder;">
  <p:dataList value="#{wFDesignBean.components}" var="a" id="airComponentsOrderList">
    <p:row rendered="#{a.functionality eq 1}">
      <h:outputLabel id="airCompName" value="#{a.name}" title="#{a.name}" />
    </p:row>
    <p:draggable id="dragableForAirComp" for="airCompName" helper="clone"/>
  </p:dataList>
</p:tab>
```

the rendered attribute put the row empty, but it doesn't hide it. I need to hide the empty rows to make the view acceptable.

Comment: post some code snippet

Comment: without any code or explanation you should not expect an answer.

Comment: change rendered="#{a.functionality eq 1}" to rendered="true" to see if the column will be rendered or not.

Comment: if you mean that you want to know if the column is rendered or not, yes it is rendered, my question is not about the rendering its about hide the empty rows resulted from the rendering. Thanks

Comment: you set "rendered" attribute for a column not a row.

Comment: even if i set it to the row the same issue appears.

Comment: could you post how do you set the row attr.

Comment: i edited the question and there i set the render to the row attribute and as i told you still the same issue appears.

Comment: I really don't know :), but try putting draggable inside p:row.

Comment: I solved the issue by accessing the prime faces css class for the datalist and check if the <li> is empty set it display to none and it works fine, i will post it as an answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is solved by accessing the class `ui-datalist-item` of primefaces and check if the row is empty so hide it.And here is the Css function i used

```
.ui-datalist-item:empty {
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by making a function is empty to render in facet footer:

```
  <f:facet name="footer"   >
  <h:outputText value="#{myBundle.ListGroupEmpty}" rendered="#{groupController.isGroupsEmpty()}"/>
  </f:facet>
```

and

```
public boolean isGroupsEmpty(){
    if (groups == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (groups.size()<1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```